# What are headers used for in RAML?

Tags: header, raml

Working with RAML headers, can anyone help me in learning it.I am unable to find online that what actually headers are in RAML, why they are used for.

Comment: Have a look at https://raml.org/developers/raml-100-tutorial

Comment: I can not understand from there, Kindly provide me another link or some other link to learn RAML

Answer (score 0):

I think RAML spec is better place to learn about RAML than the tutorials. https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#headers

```
headers:
  Zencoder-Api-Key:
    description: The API key needed to create a new job
```

Headers refer to HTTP headers. They can be used to define authorization token, e.g. `Authorization` or `Zencoder-Api-Key`. HTTP headers can be send with you API request.